# asignacion de valores a clases compuestas C#

Tags: c#, poo, clase

tengo el siguiente problema, que puede parecer un poco tonto, pero no doy con la respuesta.
Tengo la siguiente clase

```
public class miClase
{ 
  public int miId {get; set;}
  public string miString {get; set;}
  public tipo1 miTipo1 {get; set;}
}

luego tengo otra clase tipo1
public class tipo1
{
  public int idTipo1 {get; set;}
  public string stTipo1 {get; set;}
}
```

al instanciar la clase tipo1, le puedo asignar valores de la siguiente manera

```
tipo1 t1 = new tipo1();
t1.idTipo1 = 1;
t1.stTipo1 = "hola";
```

per al instanciar la clase miClase, no puedo asignar valores a las variables de tipo1

```
miClase mc = new miClase();
mc.miId = 1;  // se puede
mc.miString = "chao"; //tambien se puede
mc.tipo1.idTipo1 = 2; // me da un mensaje de null reference
mc.tipo1.stTipo1 = "esto no vale"; // supongo que tb me da el mismo error
```

que estoy haciendo mal? 
no se puede asignar valores directamente a la clase de esta manera?
hay que instanciar obligatoriamente una variable tipo1, asignarle valores, y despues asignarsela a miClase??

Saludos

Comment: Si tienes que instanciarla.

Comment: Siguiendo el ejemplo puedes hacer así: `mc.tipo1 = t1;`

Comment: y no existe algna forma de evitar esto? te lo pregunto porque la clase real que tengo que pasarle datos, es gigantesca..  son cientos de clases y subclases, que foeman una estructura muy grande, y para armar un ejemplo completo, tendria que estar escribiendo codigo como chino... que otras opciones tengo en este caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
miClase mc = new miClase();
mc.miId = 1;  // se puede
mc.miString = "chao"; //tambien se puede
mc.tipo1.idTipo1 = 2; // me da un mensaje de null reference
mc.tipo1.stTipo1 = "esto no vale"; // supongo que tb me da el mismo error
```

tipo1 es la clase, el objeto es miTipo1 , o sea no vas a poder declarar directamente llamando a la clase
Para que te funcione deberías crear la clase miClase de la siguiente manera

```
    public class miClase
    { 
      public int miId {get; set;}
      public string miString {get; set;}
      public tipo1 miTipo1 = new tipo1();
    }
```

Y en la asignación de las variables

```
        miClase mc = new miClase();
        mc.miId = 1;
        mc.miString = "chao";
        mc.miTipo1.idTipo1 = 2; 
        mc.miTipo1.stTipo1 = "esto no vale";
```

Saludos

Comment: entiendo lo que me explicas, pero la verdad, es que no me sirve de esa manera, ya que no puedo intervenir las clases que me pasaron. solo las puedo usar, es decir, meterle datos, y leerlas.

Comment: Si podes da un ejemplo mas claro, la única diferencia con lo que vos tenes es que tenes que usar el New @LuisGabrielFabres

Comment: mira.. el ejemplo que puse, lo fabrique yo, pero no es en realidad las clases que estoy usando.. como comentaba antes, son cientos de clases.. creo que me faltaria pagina para poner un ejemplo real. el tema es que quiero evitar tener que modificar las clases, ya que estan referenciadas desde otro proyecto al cual no tengo acceso, y por otro lado, instanciar cada subtipo de datos, me llevaria mucho tiempo hacerlo..  para referencia, te comento que estoy usando clases del  protocolo HL7 (protocolo usado en medicina). gracias por tu paciencia. saludos

Comment: Es que no vas a poder usar las variables de la clase tipo1 si no instancias la clase en miClase, o sea tenes que usar el new si o si, salvo que quieras crear la clase tipo1 estatica, lo cual no se si te sirve para tu caso porque no lo estas mencionando @LuisGabrielFabres

Comment: Lo mas sencillo que puedes hacer es utilizar algo como esto: mc.miTipo1 = new tipo1 {idTipo1 = 2, stTipo1 = "esto no vale"};

Comment: ok, queda claro que tendre que ver la manera de pasarle los valores a la clase instanciando las subclases, de las subclases.. hasta el infinito... muchas gracias por las respuestas, y por el tiempo. saludos

Comment: No se cual sea tu problema especifico ya que no lo comentaste, pero fijate en google si los conceptos herencia o listas puedan resolver tus problemas. Acordate si tu duda esta resuelta marcar el tilde. Saludos @LuisGabrielFabres

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te dice el error es que no se ha definido ningún objeto para la clase `tipo1` en la clase `mc`. Si no puedes tocar las propiedades de `miClase` para que se haga un instanciado automático como proponían en otra respuesta, puedes crearlo manualmente utilizando `new` como cualquier otro objeto:

```
miClase mc = new miClase();
mc.miId = 1;  // se puede
mc.miString = "chao"; //tambien se puede
mc.tipo1 = new tipo1(); // se crea un nuevo objeto de tipo1 en la variable mc
mc.tipo1.idTipo1 = 2; // esto no debería darte ya ningún mensaje de null reference
mc.tipo1.stTipo1 = "esto vale"; // y este tampoco debería darte ningún error
```

También puedes utilizar el formato corto que te indicaban en otro comentario:

```
mc.miTipo1 = new tipo1 {idTipo1 = 2, stTipo1 = "esto vale"};
```